# remove html tag in android

Tags: java, android, html, xml-parsing, stringbuffer

I have follows below XML feed:

```
<Description>
  <p>Touch, tap, flip, slide! You don&#39;t just read Books, you experience it.</p>
</Description>
```

Here I have to display the description like

**Touch,tap,flip,slide! You don 39.just read the Books, you experience it.**

Here I have handled the parser like:

```
   public static String removeHTML(String htmlString)
  {
  // Remove HTML tag from java String    
String noHTMLString = htmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");

// Remove Carriage return from java String
noHTMLString = noHTMLString.replaceAll("\r", "<br/>");
noHTMLString = noHTMLString.replaceAll("<([bip])>.*?</\1>", "");
// Remove New line from java string and replace html break
noHTMLString = noHTMLString.replaceAll("\n", " ");
noHTMLString = noHTMLString.replaceAll("\"", "&quot;");
noHTMLString = noHTMLString.replaceAll("<(.*?)\\>"," ");//Removes all items in brackets
noHTMLString = noHTMLString.replaceAll("<(.*?)\\\n"," ");//Must be undeneath
noHTMLString = noHTMLString.replaceFirst("(.*?)\\>", " ");
noHTMLString = noHTMLString.replaceAll("&nbsp;"," ");
noHTMLString = noHTMLString.replaceAll("&amp;"," ");
return noHTMLString;

    }
```

In endElement :

```
   public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)throws SAXException {
  currentElement = false;
   if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Description")){
   sitesList.setDescription(currentValue);
   String Sub_arry=n+currentValue;
   Appscontent.Sub_arraylistdes.add(Sub_arry);
   String stringWithoutHTML=removeHTML(currentValue);
   System.out.println("description value----->"+n+att_ID+"------>>"+stringWithoutHTML);}
```

Now i have to run the app means the html tag is displayed with my description...Here how can I remove the HTML tag? please provide me solution for these ???

i wish to display the description without Html tags...please provide e solution for these.

**EDIT:**

```
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Description")){
    sitesList.setDescription(currentValue);
    String Sub_arry=n+currentValue;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(Sub_arry);
     String newString = sb.toString();
      Appscontent.Sub_arraylistdes.add(newString);
       System.out.println("description value----->"+n+att_ID+"------>>"+newString);}
```

**EDIT:**

```
  public static String html2text(String html) {
  return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
    }
```

In endElement:

```
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Description")){
    sitesList.setDescription(currentValue);
    String Sub_arry=n+currentValue;
    Appscontent.Sub_arraylistdes.add(Sub_arry);
      String stringWithoutHTML=html2text(currentValue);
       System.out.println("description value----->"+n+att_ID+"------>>"+stringWithoutHTML);}
```

But i didn't get  the o/p..pls provide me solution for these ???  how can i remove the html tags in these description...

Answer (score 17):

You can easily remove any HTML tag in Android using the built-in HTML class in Android. Import `android.text.Html;`. Now, considering "data" is your String variable which has HTML tags, you use `Html.fromHtml(data).toString()` to get back the string without any HTML tags.

Answer (score 8):

Simple method to remove html. This will return non-html formatted text

```
 private String removeHtml(String html) {
    html = html.replaceAll("<(.*?)\\>"," ");
    html = html.replaceAll("<(.*?)\\\n"," ");
    html = html.replaceFirst("(.*?)\\>", " ");
    html = html.replaceAll("&nbsp;"," ");
    html = html.replaceAll("&amp;"," ");
    return html;
}
```

To formatted according html tag and remove tag.

```
Html.fromHtml(data).toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to add the [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) library, import it and use it as follows:

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String plain = Html.fromHtml("your_html_string").toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin you can simply do it with this extension function -

```
fun String.removeHtml() = replace("\\<.*?\\>".toRegex(), "")
```

and you can call this function as

```
val cleanString = yourHtmlString.removeHtml()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private int iMobileVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    String strResonseTemplate = data.getStringExtra("template"); //getting HTML data in string

    if (iMobileVersion >= 24) {
                                mEtReply.setText(Html.fromHtml(strResonseTemplate, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));// this code only works on and above API 24, and removes all HTML tag, but gives same view as HTML in Edittext.
                            } else {
                                mEtReply.setText(Html.fromHtml(strResonseTemplate).toString()); // bellow API level 24 we are removing only HTML tags, it will show as normal text.

                            }
```

Hope this will be helpfull :)

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge you can get data by spannable interface.

Try using this:

> Spanned spannable =
>   Html.fromHtml(arrayList.get(position).getBusinessDescription());
>   System.out.println("description
>   value----->"+n+att_ID+"------>>"+spannable);

check the below link for more details:

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add these few lines of code and you are done .

```
String html=(jsonObject1.getString("originaltext"));
            html = html.replaceAll("<(.*?)\\>"," ");
            html = html.replaceAll("<(.*?)\\\n"," ");
            html = html.replaceFirst("(.*?)\\>", " ");
            html = html.replaceAll("&nbsp;"," ");
            html = html.replaceAll("&amp;"," ");
            newsModel.setNews(html);
            Log.d("originaltext: ",html);
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
//Patter to detect elements contained into "<>"
private static final Pattern REMOVE_TAGS = Pattern.compile("<.+?>");

//Method to remove the html tags contained in a String variable
public static String removeTags(String string) 
{
  //validate that at least one value contains the string
  if (string == null || string.length() == 0) 
  {
     return string;
  }
  //Function to find the matches within the chain and the pattern       
  Matcher m = REMOVE_TAGS.matcher(string);
  //replace <> element with ""
  return m.replaceAll("");
}

//Implementation of the method to eliminate html tags and place inside a Text control
this.itemView.setText(
 Html.fromHtml(
  new String(removeTags("<h1>My Title here</h1>").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8")
 )
);
```

Comment: Hi Jose!  This could be a great answer, can you elaborate and explain some of the steps to the question asker?  That would help tremendously.