# How to remove html tag like <br> in android

Tags: java, android, json

I am using json in my android application,actually in list view its showing with html tag in my text also,how can i display only the text avoiding the html tags

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements FetchDataListener
{
    private ProgressDialog dialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);   
        initView();
    }



    private void initView()
    {
        // show progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");
        String url = "http://floating-wildwood-1154.herokuapp.com/posts.json";
        FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
        task.execute(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchComplete(List<Application> data)
    {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if ( dialog != null )
            dialog.dismiss();
        // create new adapter
        ApplicationAdapter adapter = new ApplicationAdapter(this, data);
        // set the adapter to list
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchFailure(String msg)
    {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if ( dialog != null )
            dialog.dismiss();
        // show failure message
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Applicationadapter.java

```
public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Application>
{
    private List<Application> items;

    public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, List<Application> items)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.app_custom_list, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View v = convertView;
        if ( v == null )
        {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.app_custom_list, null);
        }
        Application app = items.get(position);
        if ( app != null )
        {
            TextView titleText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
            if ( titleText != null )
                titleText.setText(app.getContent());
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

In my listview its displaying like this

hello`<br>`

frnds`'<br>`'

gudmrng`'<br>'`

its showing with html tag,i want only the text data alone,the text has to display in my listview.

Comment: str=str.replace("<br>","");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196414/remove-html-tag-in-android/37851323#37851323

Answer (score 11):

use [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) for showing text with html tags in TextView.Example

`String str_without_html=Html.fromHtml("back to work<br>").toString();`

Comment: could you explain clearly what are the lines i have to add ,where i have to add the lines @prosper

Comment: @IBetterCommunity : you will need to use `Html.fromHtml(your_string_here_which_contains_html_tags).toString()` before setting text to TextView or any View to remove all html tags

Comment: where i have to add these line in mainactivity.java or where else i have to add these line,is this one line is enough ?

Comment: @IBetterCommunity : plz also add ApplicationAdapter class code with question and yes this line is enough for removing html tags from string

Comment: @IBetterCommunity : change `titleText.setText(app.getContent());` line to `titleText.setText(Html.fromHtml(app.getContent()).toString());` in ApplicationAdapter class

Comment: i added my application adapter also here,actually in my listview its displaying depends upon the server side,if i add anything in my website it will displays in listview,while displaying in listview it shows with html tag also,i want to remove only html tags while displaying

Comment: @IBetterCommunity : ok, just change `titleText.setText(app.getContent());` line to `titleText.setText(Html.fromHtml(app.getContent()).toString());` in ApplicationAdapter class. this will remove all HTML Tags from String before passing to setText method

Comment: thanks dude,its working fine,change your answer for future guys for reference

Comment: You should accept the answer of @ρяσѕρєяK instead of giving your own answer...

Comment: ok dude,i will remove my answere,is it ok for you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712961/how-to-use-post-method-in-android-using-json,can you see this question i am strucking with that question

Comment: Html.fromHtml(my_string).toString()
this function also remove these (&amp;) from the string?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `<br>` Tag

```
url =  url.replaceAll("<br>", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
String s = value.replaceAll("<br>","");
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions is generally require either regex - which is an error-prone approach - or installing a third-party library such as jsoup or jericho. A better solution on Android devices is just to make use of the Html.fromHtml() function:

**Code**

```
public String stripHtml(String html) {
    return Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
}
```

This uses Android's built in Html parser to build a Spanned representation of the input html without any html tags. The "Span" markup is then stripped by converting the output back into a string.

Comment: where i have to use this code,its in my main activity am i correct?any other code is needed or its enough?

Comment: you can use this function anywhere. this function will return the string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string  please gothrough this URL.

Comment: @Karthik why not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502759/how-to-strip-or-escape-html-tags-in-android :D

Comment: @PankajKumar the answer will help for someone ...

Comment: right but the link which I have given is the match.. right? The accepted answer is same as your... :D

Comment: streight away i posted the answer without giving url. because he can get the answer faster and easily based on their force he no need to search somewhere.

Comment: @PankajKumar,are u there,its again coming the same problem why